# How to list and sort pictures with just one number in its name?

Tags: bash, macos, sorting, command-line-interface, ls

How can I list all `jpg` with a number as a name in `bash` on a `mac`? I have a folder with several pictures all with numbers in its name.

However, I just want to have those pictures listed and sorted in `bash` with just 1 number in its name, with the following layout: `1.jpg` or `30.jpg`, but not `1-1.jpg` or `30-1-2.jpg` etc.

I tried `ls $* | sort -V`, but it gives me all pictures.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: @Jetchisel : You forgot to quote the argument to `-iname`. Also, even if it is a trivial solution, I think you should write it as answer.

Comment: @Jetchisel: That will still match `1-1.jpg`

Comment: `find . -type f ! -iname '*[0-9]-[0-9]*.jpg' | sort -V`

Comment: @Inian, deleted the first comment.

Comment: Simply `shopt -s extglob` and `echo *([^0-9])+([0-9])*([^0-9])` in bash

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: Yes with `.jpg` at the end

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I will try at home later which command works for me. Thank you all.

Comment: @Inian Yes, if listing only .jpg files is desired.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any third party tool for this, just enable `bash` extended globbing (if not enabled by default). The `nullglob` option allows filename patterns which match no files to expand to a null string, rather than themselves

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
```

If you are sure, there can't be filenames containing other alphanumeric characters, then to exclude filenames containing `-`, all you need to do is

```
printf '%s\n' !(*-*).jpg
```

or be specific to match only filenames with digits as

```
printf '%s\n' [[:digit:]]!(*-*).jpg
```

Or wrap this over in a sub-shell to avoid setting the glob options persistent in your interactive shell.

```
( shopt -s extglob nullglob ; printf '%s\n' [[:digit:]]!(*-*).jpg ; ) |
sort -V
```

---

As to why your attempt didn't work, `ls $*` can never work, because `$*` is a special `bash` shell variable created by concatenating all the command line arguments passed and joined by the value of `IFS`. Were you trying to pass `*` as the argument and process `$*` inside a function/script and sort on the list returned?

Answer (score 1):

Use Bash's built-in extended globbing patterns.

```sh
shopt -s extglob 
ls +([[:digit:]]).{{[jJ][pP],[pP][nN]}[gG],{[gG],[tT]}[iI][fF]?([fF])} | sort -n
```

or with case insensitive globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob nocaseglob
ls +([[:digit:]]).{{jp,pn}g,{g,t}if?(f)} | sort -n
```

Or if you look only for lowercase `.jpg`:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
ls +([[:digit:]]).jpg | sort -n
```

Comment: @Inian the option is `nocaseglob` for filename matching. `nocasematch` affects string comparisons tests.